# How to find list of event listeners on a DOM element?

Tags: dart, dart-html

Is there a way to find a list of Event listeners for a dom node in dart?

for example,

html:

```
..
<span id="hello"> ...</span>
```

Lets assume there are listeners on the span element. Is there a way to find out all the event listeners on it? Maybe too much to ask on where the event listeners are located as well.

Comment: There is no Dart way to get this information AFAIK. Related properties are private. If you know how to get them using JS you might be able use dart-js-interop to get that information.

Comment: I assumed you're looking for a way to do this in Dart code.

Comment: I was looking for either through dart code or while inspection. Mostly improve my debugging productivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Event Listener Breakpoints" in sources tab. 
Do inspect element then there's a tab on the right for event listeners, but it can be hard to follow.

Comment: Interesting, Ill take a look at it. Thanks